# mysql_real_connect gives segmentation fault - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, mysql

I'm trying to build a queue processor which grabs tasks jobs from mysql and I need the mysql connector variable to be global, because I need to use it in multiple functions. Here is the code:

```
...

MYSQL *connect;

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
...
   connect = mysql_init(NULL);
   if (connect == NULL) { do something and end }
   mysql_real_connect(connect, "127.0.0.1", "username", "password" , "database", 0, 0, 0);
...
   return 0;
}
```

Whatever I try I get en error when calling the mysql_real_connect function. Please help!

Comment: Try `mysql_real_connect(connect, "127.0.0.1", "username", "password" , "database", 0, NULL, 0);`

Comment: Again segmentation fault.

Comment: hm maybe: `MYSQL mysql; mysql_init(&mysql); mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "127.0.0.1", "username", "password" , "database", 0, NULL, 0);` ?

Comment: I've also tried that and then passing the reference to mysql_init, but it also results in a segmentation fault :(

Comment: Are You sure that the bug is in this part of code?

Comment: It has to be, because this is the first time I use the _connect_ variable and mysql_real_connect.

Comment: One other thing probably worth mentioning is that when I move _connect_ into main, it works. So this happens only when _connect_ is global. Not sure why though.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is getting `connect` confused with another variable or function name (like socket `connect`). Try a different variable name - should have produced a warning though.

Comment: @The Dark, that was it! Though, it didn't give me any warnings or anything. Post the answer so I can flag it as correct :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the compiler is getting `connect` confused with another variable or function name (like socket `connect`). Try a different variable name - should have produced a warning though.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error and successfully resolve:

```
connect = mysql_init(connect); // mysql_init should both pass in and out
f (connect == NULL) { do something and end }
if (!mysql_real_connect(connect, "127.0.0.1", "username", "password" , "database", 0, 0, 0)) {
  exit(1);
}
```